# Change TextSize in a container without css. Directly in HTML Document

Tags: html, css

is there a way to change the TextSize and Textcolor directly in the HTML Document?
It must be this kind of box (same class) because I need the backroundcolor.
Unfortunately it always has the same textsize.

This is the html line:

Welcher Button reagiert schneller?

[Picture of HTML element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fw5bS.png)

I know it is probably a very easy solution but I just can't find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can not set a `font-size` via HTML, you can however use CSS *inside* a HTML document to edit *any* `property` like so:

Inside the `head` > `style` element (then however it is recommended to use `classes` [like I did] or `ids`).

```
<head>
  <style>
    .box {
      font-size: 32px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
</body>
```

Or directly inside the specific element's first tag, by adding a `style=""` attribute.

```
<div style="font-size: 32px;">
  <!-- content -->
</div>
```

In this example I used a `div` you can really do this on any element and set the `font-size` to `32px` you can choose any number and even different units.

Answer (score 0):

Simplicius has a good response.

The closest you can get to what you’re asking for (as your question was originally worded) would be something no longer supported in html5

It still works but use at your own risk.

```
<font size=2 color=red face=Arial>
    your text
</font>
```